# How to add ThreadId and ProcessId into the log output for each entry

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, microsoft-extensions-logging

is there a simple way to add **ThreadId** and **ProcessId** into the logs through **Microsoft.Extensions.Logging** without writing my own LoggingProvider?

Simply following code

```
Logger.LogInformation("This is a test of the emergency broadcast system.");
```

should produce the following or similar output. *(please assume I'm talking about ConsoleLogger)*

```
info: [{ProcessId}:{ThreadId}] This is a test of the emergency broadcast system.
```

> - For those who are familiar with *serilog*, I'm looking for the features called  **output template** and **defining global property**
> - Please do not suggest any third party library

Comment: [Serilog – Add thread (and process) ID to the log file](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2019/02/22/serilog-add-thread-id-to-the-log-file/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, there's nothing built into for the console logger.